# Why isn't this ng-idle implementation connecting modal and styling?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, modal-dialog, ng-idle

I am trying to get `ng-idle` to hook up to `css` and `modal` [the way it looks in this working example at this link](https://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng-idle/).  I have interpreted the code at the link to mean that I should type the code below to implement it, but the code below does not hook the controller or the styling up to the view.  **What specific changes need to be made to the code below to successfully implement ng-idle the way it looks in the demo link above, with modal warning and with styling for the buttons, etc.?**

The situation can be recreated on your computer by [downloading a fully functioning MINIMAL reproduction by clicking the link to this file sharing site](https://jumpshare.com/v/w9DOYA3N9CnISApmiawZ), and then viewing the contents of `index.html` and `app.js` which are currently the following:

`index.html` is:

```
<html ng-app="demo">
  <head>
    <title title>NgIdle Sample</title> 
  </head>
  <body>

<section data-ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
{{ started }}  <!-- this SYSO of the `start` variable does not print -->
  <p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-ng-hide="started" data-ng-click="start()">Start Demo</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-show="started" data-ng-click="stop()">Stop Demo</button>
 </p>
</section>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="warning-dialog.html">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <h3>You're Idle. Do Something!</h3>
  </div>
  <div idle-countdown="countdown" ng-init="countdown=5" class="modal-body">
   <progressbar max="5" value="5" animate="false" class="progress-striped active">You'll be logged out in {{countdown}} second(s).</progressbar>
  </div>

</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="timedout-dialog.html">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <h3>You've Timed Out!</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <p>
      You were idle too long. Normally you'd be logged out, but in this demo just do anything and you'll be reset.
   </p>
 </div>
</script>

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ng-idle/angular-idle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And `app.js` is:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('demo', ['ngIdle', 'ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, Idle, Keepalive, $modal){
      $scope.started = false;

      function closeModals() {
        if ($scope.warning) {
          $scope.warning.close();
          $scope.warning = null;
        }

        if ($scope.timedout) {
          $scope.timedout.close();
          $scope.timedout = null;
        }
      }

      $scope.$on('IdleStart', function() {
        closeModals();

        $scope.warning = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'warning-dialog.html',
          windowClass: 'modal-danger'
        });
      });

      $scope.$on('IdleEnd', function() {
        closeModals();
      });

      $scope.$on('IdleTimeout', function() {
        closeModals();
        $scope.timedout = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'timedout-dialog.html',
          windowClass: 'modal-danger'
        });
      });

      $scope.start = function() {
        closeModals();
        Idle.watch();
        $scope.started = true;
      };

      $scope.stop = function() {
        closeModals();
        Idle.unwatch();
        $scope.started = false;

      };
    })
    .config(function(IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider) {
      IdleProvider.idle(5);
      IdleProvider.timeout(5);
      KeepaliveProvider.interval(10);
    })
 .run(['Idle', function(Idle) {
      Idle.watch();
    }]);
```

Now that the problem is recreated, what changes need to be made to the code above to get it to implement modal and styling as in the example/demo at the link at top of the OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the project you TARed, there were four things:

1. You need to make sure `ng-app="demo"` attribute is added to the `html` or `body` element. The value `demo` should be changed to match whatever you call your application when you define your application module in this line of `app.js`: `angular.module('demo', [/* etc. */])`
2. Make sure you include `ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` and not `ui-bootstrap.min.js`; the latter does not include HTML templates for the directives (with the expectation that you'd supply them yourself), and the former does. See the UI-Bootstrap [getting started guide](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/getting_started).
3. The version of UI-Bootstrap you are referencing is more recent than the version I wrote the demo with. `$modal` has been renamed to [`$uibModal`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), so just search and replace that token.
4. Make sure you include Bootstrap in the CSS of your application. You started this app using a Yeoman generator, and that generator appears to compile Bootstrap SASS into CSS in `styles/main.css`.

Some of these things (1,2, and 4) were probably already set up for you by the Yeoman generator, and you hacked it apart trying to paste in the ng-idle demo code.

Here's your index.html (with all the commented out stuff removed):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body ng-app="demo">
  <!--[if lte IE 8]
  <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  [endif]//-->

  <div class="header">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">client</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a ng-href="#/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a ng-href="#/">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div ng-view="">
      <section data-ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
        {{ started }}
        <!-- this SYSO of the `start` variable does not print -->
        <p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-ng-hide="started" data-ng-click="start()">Start Demo</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-show="started" data-ng-click="stop()">Stop Demo</button>
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <p><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> from the Yeoman team</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="warning-dialog.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3>You&apos;re Idle. Do Something!</h3>
    </div>
    <div idle-countdown="countdown" ng-init="countdown=5" class="modal-body">
      <progressbar max="5" value="5" animate="false" class="progress-striped active">You&apos;ll be logged out in {{countdown}} second(s).</progressbar>
    </div>

  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="timedout-dialog.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3>You&apos;ve Timed Out!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>
        You were idle too long. Normally you&apos;d be logged out, but in this demo just do anything and you&apos;ll be reset.
      </p>
    </div>
  </script>

  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/ng-idle/angular-idle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here's `app.js`:

```
  'use strict';
  angular.module('demo', ['ngIdle', 'ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, Idle, Keepalive, $uibModal){
      $scope.started = true;

      function closeModals() {
        if ($scope.warning) {
          $scope.warning.close();
          $scope.warning = null;
        }

        if ($scope.timedout) {
          $scope.timedout.close();
          $scope.timedout = null;
        }
      }

      $scope.$on('IdleStart', function() {
        closeModals();

        $scope.warning = $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: 'warning-dialog.html',
          windowClass: 'modal-danger'
        });
      });

      $scope.$on('IdleEnd', function() {
        closeModals();
      });

      $scope.$on('IdleTimeout', function() {
        closeModals();
        $scope.timedout = $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: 'timedout-dialog.html',
          windowClass: 'modal-danger'
        });
      });

      $scope.start = function() {
        closeModals();
        Idle.watch();
        $scope.started = true;
      };

      $scope.stop = function() {
        closeModals();
        Idle.unwatch();
        $scope.started = false;

      };
    })
    .config(function(IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider) {
      IdleProvider.idle(5);
      IdleProvider.timeout(5);
      KeepaliveProvider.interval(10);
    })
    .run(['Idle', function(Idle) {
      Idle.watch();
    }]);
```

I respect a hands-on approach to learning how things work, but I'd recommend you pump the brakes a little and learn about the relationship between Angular, your yeoman generator, Bootstrap, UI-Bootstrap, and ng-idle, and how to use each of these things.

Comment: I am marking this as accepted because it works on my devbox.  I notice that I can click anywhere on the web page to restart the timer, even other areas of a page (like the TOC) that are not in the `< section >` tag bound to `DemoCtrl`.  Is this because `angular-idle.js` controls the entire browser window and not just the `section` bound to `DemoCtrl`?  I am also curious if I add other controllers to other html elements in `index.html` if clicking on the html elements controlled by other controllers will also restart the ngIdle timer?  Thank you in advance for clarifying this.

Comment: @CodeMed That's correct. At this time, ng-idle waits for interrupt events on the whole document to bubble up; it does not handle per-element detection. That's out of scope of the intention of ng-idle, but I suppose a fork could be made to support this using directives. As an aside, the port I made of this for Angular 2 _can_  be used to detect activity on anything you want. That doesn't help you in Angular 1 apps, but I might rewrite ng-idle for Angular 1 to support a similar model.