# AngularJS - Detect no action for n minutes and go to default state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to Angular and would appreciate your advice. I'm using `ui.router` and I configured states like this:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/category");
$stateProvider
    .state('category', {
        url: '/category',
        templateUrl: 'category.html',
        controller: 'categoryController as catCtrl',
        reload: true
    })
    .state('category.categoryDetail', {
        url:'/:id',
        templateUrl: 'categoryDetail.html',
        controller: 'categoryDetailController as catDetailCtrl',
    })

    .state('category.categoryDetail.product', {
        url:'/product/:prod_id/:filter_model/:current_page',
        templateUrl: 'product.html',
        controller: 'productController as productCtrl'
    })
```

I need to set timeout function that checks if there is no action for 'n' minutes, then I need the website to return to the default state `'category'`. I know I could do it with `jQuery` using `setTimeout()` but I'm not sure where to embed the code.

Comment: what actions are you talking about? talking to the backend, clicks on anywhere of the screen?

Comment: In wherever you want to land first, use $timeout (just like you use jQuery's setTimeout) to countdown, and when it ends redirect the user using $location. Meantime if action happens, cancel the timeout and/or start a new one if you need to do the checking again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `app.run` .

I made an example of what you need in plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/aHj3XeCC83hHoCcu9Vix?p=preview

Copy the code and try it locally, it will work fine.

I used this answer: [auto logout with angularjs based on idle user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168330/auto-logout-with-angularjs-based-on-idle-user)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need something like [ng-idle](https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle)

Comment: Very useful, but should I repeat the same code in every controller? Because I need to "watch" from every place.

Comment: you can use it with .run