# AngularJS: how can I call a function after certain time interval?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My Scenario is:

I want to call the logout function after let says 30 mins automatically in my app. Is this possible to achieve this? And moreover, I want to know the time of the user's last interactivity with my application. Can anybody help me regarding this??

Comment: Yes you can: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: [ng-idle](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-idle) module can help

Comment: use setInterval is the best idea i hope

Comment: @RahulKamboj, `setInteval` will call a function again and again after certain interval. If it's meant to be invoked only once, then `setTimeout` is the one. Even that won't be useful in case of Angular as that function will be executed outside AngularJS context, so I think `$timeout` is the service he needs to use.

Comment: @Tech Kid, as Grundy suggested, `ng-idle` is the one that takes care of inactivity and provides callbacks to work with

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696969/angular-session-timeout-and-management

Comment: Thanks alot all of you for your wonderful answers. Please tell me about `ng-idle`. actullay im newbie in angular. I want to fire a function of logout if user don't any interactivity within 30 mins...
@georgeawg @Grundy

Comment: See this answer -- [Try ng-idle. It's simple component where you can set the timeout and warning time before the timeout is reached](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29154182/5535245).

Comment: @Grundy , @gergeawg , 
Sir, I'm getting this error now `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest` can you please help me to turn my this `$rootscope.synchronization()` function into service or factory provider in this [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/SZ9NvTo0TE6MBo4oRRSj?p=preview).. :(

Comment: @TechKid, seems this already another question

Comment: see if [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/XHZI9iwdOCdcfq8K5QEo?p=preview) helps

Comment: @Arkantos My good bro, Thanks alot. This really helped me..

Answer (score 9):

Use below for any function that requires time out. But I will not suggest this for Logout. Better you can use browser session to logout after 30 min.

```
$timeout(function() {
   // your code
}, 3000); // 3 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer 
Sir, I'm getting this error now `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest` can you please help me to turn my this `$rootscope.synchronization()` function into service or factory provider in this [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/SZ9NvTo0TE6MBo4oRRSj?p=preview).. :(

Answer (score 4):

use setTimeout()  pure javascript function that can be invoked after a time of interval

```
 setTimeout(function(){
    logout();
},5000)
```

Comment: Is this call a function once or call repeately after 5000 miliseconds ?

Comment: In case your `logout()` changes something on scope, the this won't work. You have to wrap the call to logout in `$scope.apply()` or use `$timeout` that does this implicitly

Comment: @Arkantos. Thanks alot for your answer.
Sir, I'm getting this error now `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest` can you please help me to turn my this `$rootscope.synchronization()` function into service or factory provider in this [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/SZ9NvTo0TE6MBo4oRRSj?p=preview).. :(